# bash - executing ssh command in a loop

Tags: bash

I have the loop:

```
IFS=','
for host in host1,host2
  do 
     ssh root@$host script.sh 
  done
```

When I execute the loop, ssh command works fine for host1, but for host2 I see:

```
bash: host2: command not found
```

Could you tell me where can be the problem?

Comment: `for host in {host1,host2}`

Comment: Splitting on `IFS` isn't doing what you think it is. Splitting happens on variable expansion, so it *doesn't* expand the literal value in the `for` statement, but it does split the when the `$host` variable is expanded; essentially, it runs `ssh root@host1 host2 script.sh`. This tries to run `host2` as a command on host1. Moral: splitting with `IFS` is hard to understand and you're generally better off using other methods to get things done (like arrays).

Comment: I suggest to use an array instead of splitting with a `,` delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You above script will return an output command like this

```
ssh root@host1 host2 script.sh
```

Here **host2** is considered as an argument or a command which the shell is not able to recognize and hence you are getting the above error.

Assuming your use case is to run the shell script on both hosts the following script might help you

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< host1,host2
for host in ${array[@]};   do      ssh root@$host script.sh; done
```

output command will be similar to below

```
ssh root@host1 script.sh
ssh root@host2 script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this

```
for host in host1 host2
  do 
     ssh root@$host script.sh
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

## PSSH (https://github.com/lilydjwg/pssh)

#### Create your file with hosts/ip addresses, then try following:

```
pssh -h hostfile.txt -l root -i "echo 'hello world'; another_command; exit"
```

- -h = hostfile with ip adddresses
- -l = username to use
- -i = command to execute on source
- -A = for use password